# gdb is skipping instructions

Tags: c++, gdb, shared-objects

I have limited experience with gdb and debugging shared objects in general, so I wonder if anyone could shed some light on the behavior I am seeing.

Basically I am trying to understand the internals of a poorly-documented library.  To that end, I wrote a program that makes minimal use of the library and I am trying to step through it to see what's going on.

The problem is that after a few uses of the "step" command in gdb, the program executes more than one instruction.  One reason I believe this is that eventually gdb indicates that three threads have been launched, but no where in the code do I see why that might have happened.

In the past I have tried rebuilding the library with debug symbols, but that doesn't seem to get me any further.  I am not even sure if this is relevant, since I thought gbd could still step through instructions without debug symbols (even if not having them meant it would give me less information).

In case it is relevant: I am debugging a 3-line program I wrote that links dynamically against the library of interest.  I have the source for the library but it is complicated, so I hoped gdb would shed some light on things.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What optimization options are you using? The more optimization, the harder to use with a debugger.

Comment: Are you trying to step through optimized C++ code in gdb? That would would super confusing.

Comment: @Shawn Looking at the build script for the library in question reveals that setting their DEBUG parameter to "true" means the -O0 is used.

Comment: @Shawn  Nevermind!  I wasn't using the build script properly.  I just rebuilt and set the debug option appropriately, so it seems the optimizations are off now.

Comment: If someone wants to post an answer about the optimizations I will mark it as correct.  Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

> I thought gbd could still step through instructions

It could, but the command to do so is `stepi`, not `step` that you are using.

Step steps over *lines*, which requires presence of debugging info in the sources.

Answer (score 0):

> A little bit about optimizations

**For example, this is a C Code:**

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  printf("Hello World\n");
  return 0;
}
```

**When you build with -O0, code optimization is done barely, and the code runs very slowly. This is the unoptimized code (gcc -m32):**

```
; Variables:
        ;    arg_4: 12
        ;    arg_0: 8
        ;    var_4: -4
        ;    var_8: -8
        ;    var_C: -12
        ;    var_10: -16
        ;    var_18: -24
push       ebp
mov        ebp, esp
sub        esp, 0x18
call       _main+11
pop        eax                            ; CODE XREF=_main+6

-- These lines are gone after optimization --
mov        ecx, dword [ebp+arg_4]
mov        edx, dword [ebp+arg_0]
--                                    --
lea        eax, dword [eax-0x1f5b+0x1fa6] ; "Hello World!\\n"

-- There lines are gone after optimization --
mov        dword [ebp+var_4], 0x0
mov        dword [ebp+var_8], edx
mov        dword [ebp+var_C], ecx

mov        dword [esp+0x18+var_18], eax  ; method imp___symbol_stub__printf
call       imp___symbol_stub__printf
xor        ecx, ecx                           
mov        dword [ebp+var_10], eax
mov        eax, ecx                                    
add        esp, 0x18                           
pop        ebp
ret
```

**When you build with -03, you will notice there are fewer lines. The optimized code (gcc -m32 -O3):**

```
push       ebp
mov        ebp, esp
sub        esp, 0x8
call       _main+11
pop        eax                             ; CODE XREF=_main+6
lea        eax, dword [eax-0x1f6b+0x1f9e]  ; "Hello World!"
mov        dword [esp+0x8+var_8], eax      ; "%s" for imp___symbol_stub__puts
call       imp___symbol_stub__puts
xor        eax, eax
add        esp, 0x8
pop        eep
ret
```

> The reason why unoptimized code has unnecesary lines is because the
>   main takes two arguments and saves them into registers whether you are
>   using or not without optimization, but with optimization the compiler
>   deletes these mov instructions, because the arguments are neither used
>   nor needed. Likewise, the values of registers are also saved into
>   stack variables as arguments are copied onto stack variables.